# Fix Table Width

Tags: latex

I'm trying to create my project report which needs me to write in a two column style on each page. I have a table on the last page whose width is a lot more than half the page width so I want to allow it to extend to the full page width. However, Latex overwrites on the extended part.

I tried a few things like using `\begin{table*}` instead of `\begin{table}` - but that makes the table go to the next page. (I don't like this because it's the last page of my report)

I also tried `\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]`, but that causes a compilation error.

Any ideas on this. Stuck for a while now.

Comment: Please add a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I completely understand your problem. IMO, you have a `documentclass` that defines that your text is going to be in two columns format, something like this:

`\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twocolumn]{report}`

You have a bunch of text that is your report, in this two-column format and you need to insert a table that will only use one-column format. For me, that is achieved by adding the `\onecolumn` command before the `\begin{table}` command.
When you finish with the table, you can use the `\twocolumn` command to return to your previous format.

However, using this approach I am giving you, it will move the table to the top of the next page, since AFAIK you cannot have `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` on the same page in Latex.

You can also use the `float` package to allow you to place the table where you want it with the `h` option in the table; something like this: `\begin{table}[ht]. However, this will not override what I wrote above, it will still begin in the next page if you are changing the columns' style.

For big tables, I know there is a package for working with them. I have not used it myself, but give it a try. Take a look at this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136212/how-to-use-longtable-package.